# How to turn header inside rows into columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot

How do I turn the headers inside the rows into columns?

For example I have the Dataframe below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwTTh.png)

and would like it to be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQvz.png)

EDIT:

Code to produce current df example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[2020,2021,2022], 'James':'', '  Sales': [3,4,5], '  City':'NY', '  DIV':'a', 'KIM':'', '  Sales ': [3,4,5], '  City ':'SF', '  DIV ':'b'}).T.reset_index()

index   0   1   2
0   Date    2020    2021    2022
1   James           
2     Sales 3   4   5
3     City  NY  NY  NY
4     DIV   a   a   a
5   KIM         
6     Sales     3   4   5
7     City  SF  SF  SF
8     DIV   b   b   b

looking to get 

Name   City DIV  Account  2020 2021 2022
James  NY    a    Sales    3    4    5  
KIM    SF    b    Sales    3    4    5
```

I think the best way is to iterate over the first column if the name(eg James) has no indent its turn into a column until it hits a other value (KIM).  So to find a way to categories the header which is not indent into a new column which stops when a new header comes up (KIM).

#Edit 2 there not only two names (KIM or JAMES) there is like 20 names. Or only the three second levels (Sales, City, Div). Different names have more that 3 second levels some have 7 levels. The only thing that is consistent is the Names are not indent but the second levels are.

Comment: Welcome! Does the first picture really show a loaded pandas DataFrame or is it some table, maybe in Excel or similar?

Comment: Its a table in excel. looks the same as the Dataframe.

Comment: Could you please post the code you currently have and possibly the data sample in a computable form?

Comment: @nehalem updated

Answer (score 2):

Using a slightly simpler example, this works, but it sure ain't pretty:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['James', 'Sales', 'City', 'Kim', 'Sales', 'City',],
    '2020': ['', '3', 'NY', '', '4', 'SF'],
    '2021': ['', '4', 'NY', '', '5', 'SF'],
})

def rows_to_columns(group):
    for value in group.date.values:
        if value != group.person.values[0] and value != 'Sales':
            temp_column = '_'+value
            group.loc[group['date']==value, temp_column] = group['2020']
            group[value.lower()] = (
               group[temp_column]
               .fillna(method='ffill')
               .fillna(method='bfill')
            )
            group.drop([temp_column], axis=1, inplace=True)
            pass
        pass
    return group


df.loc[df['2020']=='', 'person'] = df.date
df.person = df.person.fillna(method='ffill')
new_df = (df
      .groupby('person')
      .apply(lambda x:rows_to_columns(x))
      .drop(['date'], axis=1)
      .loc[df.date=='Sales']
)
```

The basic idea is to

1. Copy the name into a separate column and fill that column using `.fillna(method='ffill')`. This works if the assumption holds that every person's block begins with the person's name. Otherwise it wreaks havoc.
2. All other values, such as 'div' and 'city' will be converted by `row_to_columns(group)`. The function iterates over all rows in a group that are neither the person's name nor 'Sales', copies the value from the row into a temp column, creates a new column for that row and uses `ffill` and `bfill` to fill it out. It then deletes the temp column and returns the group.
3. The resulting data frame is the intended format once the column 'Sales' is dropped.

**Note**: This solution probably does not work well on larger datasets.

Comment: thank you for the comment but not 100% what I am looking for but I am going to try to play with your code.

Comment: Given your further details, you can abstract the fill method used for city to all other rows that are not 'Sales'. Looping does work but is usually not considered a good way to process data frames as pandas gets its performance superiority from not using python methods such as loops.

Comment: I amended my answer by a generalised solution for the additional columns.

Answer (score 1):

You gave more details, and I see you are not working with multi-level indexes. The best way for you would be to create the DataFrame already in the format you need in this case. The way you are creating the first DataFrame is not well structured and the information is not indexed by name (James/KIM) as they are columns with empty values, no link with the other values. The stacking you did use blank spaces on a string. Take a look at multi-indexing and generate a data frame you can work with, or create the data frame in the format you need in the end.

-- Answer considering multi-level indexes --

Using the few information provided, I see your Dataframe is stacked, it means, you have multiple indexes. The first level is person (James/KIM) and the second level is Sales/City/DIV. So your Dataframe should be created like this:

```
import pandas

multi_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('James', 'Sales'), ('James', 'City'), ('James', 'DIV'),
    ('KIM', 'Sales'), ('KIM', 'City'), ('KIM', 'DIV')])

year_2020 = pandas.Series([3, 'NY', 'a', 4, 'SF', 'b'], index=multi_index)
year_2021 = pandas.Series([4, 'NY', 'a', 5, 'SF', 'b'], index=multi_index)
year_2022 = pandas.Series([5, 'NY', 'a', 6, 'SF', 'b'], index=multi_index)

frame = { '2020': year_2020, '2021': year_2021, '2022': year_2022} 

df = pandas.DataFrame(frame)

print(df)

            2020 2021 2022
James Sales    3    4    5
      City    NY   NY   NY
      DIV      a    a    a
KIM   Sales    4    5    6
      City    SF   SF   SF
      DIV      b    b    b
```

Now that you have the multi_level DataFrame, you have many ways to transform it. This is what we will do to make it one level:

```
sales_df = df.xs('Sales', axis=0, level=1).copy()
div_df = df.xs('DIV', axis=0, level=1).copy()
city_df = df.xs('City', axis=0, level=1).copy()
```

The results will be:

```
print(sales)

      2020 2021 2022
James    3    4    5
KIM      4    5    6

print(div_df)

      2020 2021 2022
James    a    a    a
KIM      b    b    b

print(city_df)

      2020 2021 2022
James   NY   NY   NY
KIM     SF   SF   SF
```

You are discarding any information regarding DIV or City changes from years, so we can reduce the City and DIV dataframe to a Series, taking the first one as reference:

```
div_series = div_df.iloc[:,0]
city_series = city_df.iloc[:,0]
```

Take the sales DF as reference, and add the City and DIV series:

```
sales_df['DIV'] = div_series
sales_df['City'] = city_series
sales_df['Account'] = 'Sales'
```

Now reorder the columns as you wish:

```
sales_df = sales_df[['City', 'DIV', 'Account', '2020', '2021', '2022']]

print(sales_df)

      City DIV Account 2020 2021 2022
James   NY   a   Sales    3    4    5
KIM     SF   b   Sales    4    5    6
```

Comment: thank you very much. Sorry for lack of clarity. The only issue is there not only two names (KIM or JAMES) there is like 30 names. Or only three second levels (Sales, City, Div). Different names have more than 3 second levels some have 7 levels. The only thing that is consistent is the Names are not indented but the second levels are.